# Between two java application layer i have implemented a buffer using BlockingQueue. But don't want any lock when put and take happens

Tags: java

I am building a high processing throughput application. So between two layers, i have implemented a buffer using BlockingQueue. But don't want any lock when put and take happens.

So which queue I can use or is there any other solution which will lock put and take so that speed is faster.

Now I am facing slowness while take because put is so faster so most of the time it's locking to take. So it's making the queue to grow up and slower in processing.

Thank you, everyone.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your problem is, but you can use `BlockingQueue#poll()` to not block on an empty queue.

Comment: I highly doubt that the amount of time it takes to lock is your problem, probably your consumer takes more time to process than your producer.

Comment: How many producers / consumers will be using the queue?

Comment: Can you display your code please?

Comment: @Pranab And if your consumer is spending most of its time in `take()`, the put *isn't* faster and  the queue *isn't* growing.

Comment: @Oleg Of course, stupid of me.

Comment: Thanks to everyone.
Actually, my producer work is just put into the queue and consumer work is just take from the queue and assign the same to the available thread.

In this also I could observe that sometimes buffer queue is holding quite a number of requests.

So in this case how the consumer is not able to match up with the speed of producer when their work is similar.

Is producer locking the queue while producer trying to put the data or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976940/which-java-blocking-queue-is-most-efficient-for-single-producer-single-consumer), it looks like your needs are the same.

I wouldn't recommend to implement your own queue, even if you feel any of that is still too slow.

Comment: Thank You.

Thanks to everyone.
Actually, my producer work is just put into the queue and consumer work is just take from the queue and assign the same to the available thread.

In this also I could observe that sometimes buffer queue is holding quite a number of requests.

So in this case how the consumer is not able to match up with the speed of producer when their work is similar.

Is producer locking the queue while producer trying to put the data or vice versa?

Comment: Race conditions show up during concurrent write operations on the same memory, so concurrent read operations aren't usually problematic. In this case, write operations would be objects insertions, while read operations would be object remove operations; I would guess the queue has a mechanism similar to 2 different locks: one for inserting and the other for removing objects. This way, producer wouldn't block a consumer's removing operation while inserting an object, or at least as long as the queue isn't empty and the producer is inserting the first object